# How do I get Mac Toolbar Items that look like the standard toolbar buttons?

Tags: macos, nstoolbar

I'm working on some updates to my first Mac app and I'm trying to get my window's toolbar buttons to look like the toolbar buttons on EVERY standard Mac app. However, for the life of me, I can't find a button type or a barbutton type that gets me what I'm looking for. Am I missing something?

Here is an image showing several Mac apps (Preview, Finder, and Safari) with toolbars at the top which have very-slighty rounded corner buttons which also have a slight gradient on them, etc.

[image]

However, in my .xib I've got a toolbar and I've dropped every kind of button I can find on the thing and nothing looks like the standard Mac button.

[image]

The first button looks pretty close, but it's clearly not the same color. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `NSSegmentedControls`.

Comment: Even if I'm only using one button which is a one-time click and release?

Comment: If I do use a Segmented Control, where do I get the images? With iOS there are a set of standard button icons I can choose from for standard actions. Anything like that for Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Matt Ball is right - you can use `NSSegmentedControl`s, even for single one-time click buttons. Just set the number of segments to 1, and set the mode to "Select None".

[One of my shipping apps](http://videobuffetapp.com) uses this technique, see below:
[image: Toolbar with NSSegmentedControls]

All of the controls there are `NSSegmentedControl`, including the single one.

**Update**: there are a few standard button icons which are meant for toolbars. The [NSImage Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-SW53) has a list.

In the above screenshot, only two of the buttons are using built-in images: NSLeftFacingTriangleTemplate, and NSRightFacingTriangleTemplate. The others I drew myself.

Comment: Where do you get the icons for the buttons? Is there a standard lib distributed by Apple?